# Any API change for usb device enabling and disabling using c# on windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I want to toggle my usb enabled device from enable to disable and vice-versa.
I used the NetworkAdapter api to toggle usb in Windows 7 and It works fine. However when I use the same piece of code for windows 8.1,even though the api has disabled my usb device,the change does not get reflected in the Device Manager. I can confirm that the device has REALLY got disabled once I eject and reconnect my usb.
I want to know if there are any api changes for windows 8.1 that I may be unaware of. If not where am I going wrong?

My piece of code is:

```
switch (requiredstatus)
  {
    case "Disable":
       SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_NetworkAdapter","NetConnectionStatus=2");
       ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
       foreach (ManagementObject device in search.Get())
         {
          NetworkAdapter adapter = new NetworkAdapter(device);

          // Identify the adapter you wish to disable here. 
          // Here, we're selecting the LAN adapters.
          if (adapter.Name.Contains("Device1"))
            {
              //Console.WriteLine("Disable");
               adapter.Disable();
               result = true;
            }
    }
  break;
  case "Enable":
     SelectQuery query1 = new SelectQuery("Win32_NetworkAdapter","NetConnectionStatus=0");
     ManagementObjectSearcher search1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query1);
     foreach (ManagementObject device in search1.Get())
       {
        NetworkAdapter adapter = new NetworkAdapter(device);

         // Identify the adapter you wish to disable here. 
         // Here, we're selecting the LAN adapters.
         if (adapter.Name.Contains("Device1"))
            {
             //Console.WriteLine("Enable");
              adapter.Enable();
              result = true;
             }
        }
  break;
 }
```

Comment: The solution is quiet simple! Windows-8,Windows-8.1 needs administrator priveleges to make any change to the network adapters. Thus,the problem gets solved if we explicitly run the piece of code as administrator.To do so,just right-click the executable and select "RUN as administrator".